# Table join with scalar valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to apply a join between a table and a scalar-valued function. I have been investigating and I think that it is not possible, but as I do not find any final conclusion saying that I want to be sure.

Do you know if it is possible?

I tried the following statement (do not work):

```
Select * 
from T1
join SVFunction on T1.id=SVFunction.id
```

And also this one (do not work):

```
Select * 
from T1
outer apply SVFunction (T1.id)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to try the following query

```
Select * ,SVFunction(id)
from T1
```

[Scalar valued function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx) return single value (not table) so you cannot use joins.

If it is a table valued function you can use the following as another way then Using `Apply`:

```
Select T1.* ,T2.*
From T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM SVFunction) AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

And Maybe the problem is in the function code. so you can read more about **Using Apply** in this [Technet topic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is solved. Your first query is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
from T1
JOIN (VALUES(SVFunction)) f(id) on T1.id=f.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT SVFunction () as id) join T1 on T1.id = SVFunction.id
```