# Cross Apply of scalar function call with other Joins

Tags: t-sql

I have a view that looks like this. It returns 40K rows:

```
create view dbo.vwGetEmployeeSales
as

select 
e.FullName,
e.EmplCode,
s.TotalSales,
(select [Global].dbo.[fn_getLastSaleDate]('Cars')) as 'LastProcessedDate'
from Empl t inner join IndSales s on
t.EmplCode = s.EmplCode
where 
t.IsActive = 1
```

The query returns correct data, but I want to move the function call `[Global].dbo.[fn_getLastSaleDate]('Cars')` to the bottom.

I tried adding a `cross join`, but I'm getting a syntax error. This is what I tried but naturally doesn't work:

```
select 
e.FullName,
e.EmplCode,
s.TotalSales,
LastProcessedDate
from Empl t inner join IndSales s on
t.EmplCode = s.EmplCode
cross apply 
(select [Global].dbo.[fn_getLastSaleDate]('Cars')) 
where 
t.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Your syntax error is that you don't alias your subquery or gunna be its column one either.

Comment: Also if your function returned a table you can simply *apply* it and the optimiser can potentially inline it if it's not able to already.

Comment: The function returns a date.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here, scalar-valued functions return a single value so joins cannot be used.

[Table join with scalar valued function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759989/table-join-with-scalar-valued-function)